# Angular IMG OnError not working on Firefox when SRC has invalid XSS

Tags: angular, image, typescript, firefox

I am trying to display an image base from user's input url. It works for successful cases. But when I try to input XSS urls, the `onError` event of `img` tag is not called on FireFox. (works on Chrome and IE)

Here is my stackblitz app url: https://angular-dwlzbn.stackblitz.io

You can view it on chrome and firefox to test.

I am testing XSS urls like:

- `http://www.test.src ;>`
- `http://www.img.src="x" onerror=alert(document);/>`

I need help to catch the error even when using FireFox. My real code uses spinner, and I am hiding it when `onerror` is called. So in firefox, the spinner is stuck.

Here's my html:

```
<form #testForm="ngForm">
    <div>
      <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="URL" placeholder="Type Url Here" name="image" #image="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="imageUrl" />
      <mat-error *ngIf="image.invalid && (image.dirty || image.touched)">
        <div *ngIf="image.errors.invalidImage">Image is invalid.</div>
      </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div class="header-image-preview">
      <img *ngIf="!!imageUrl" [src]="imageUrl" (load)="onImageLoad()" (error)="onImageError()" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and here's a part of my TS file:

```
  imageUrl: string;
  @ViewChild(NgForm) testForm: NgForm;

  public onImageLoad() {
    this.testForm.controls['image'].setErrors(null);
  }

  public onImageError() {
    this.testForm.controls['image'].setErrors({ 'invalidImage': true });
  }
```

You can view the entire example code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dwlzbn